# Delete files in current folder that has specific text in filename

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I am trying to use a `batch` script to delete files that has a `(` in its name.  For example, the file that I would like to delete has the name "Test1 - Copy (5).txt".

I tried this command but it does not work:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' 
    findstr /l /i /m /c:"(" "C:\Users\Desktop\New folder\*.*"
') do echo del "%%a"
```

Can you assist me in getting the correct code to delete the files that has a `(` in its name?  Thanks!

Comment: The `echo` displays everything after it. If the correct files are being listed, remove the `echo`. Otherwise, simply try `del *(*` to use wildcards.

Comment: The code that you've shown is designed to show the names of all of the files that **contain** the character `(`.

Comment: @SomethingDark, I tried both your suggestions but I could not get the files to delete.

Comment: @Magoo, how to modify the code so that if the filename contains a "(", the file gets deleted?

Comment: The only reasons I can think of that the files wouldn't delete are if 1) they're in use or 2) you're not in the right folder. Try `del "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\New folder\*(*"`.

Comment: You solution worked.  I had to refresh my screen to see the file deleted.  Thanks!

Comment: @SomethingDark, do you want to post your comment as the solution since it worked for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when someone online gives you code that could be destructive (like code to delete a bunch of files), they'll preface the delete command with an `echo` so that you can see what commands would be run. In order to actually run the command, simply remove the `echo`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /l /i /m /c:"(" "C:\Users\Desktop\New folder\*.*"') do del "%%~a"
```

However, this is a lot of typing (and it's doing a case-insensitive search for an open parentheses for some reason), so you can simply use wildcards to delete any files whose name contain the string you're looking for:

```
del "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\New folder\*(*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to remove specific string from file name in any directory

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Set the specific text you want to remove
set "text_to_remove=your_text"

rem Loop through each file in the current directory
for %%F in (*) do (
    set "filename=%%~nF"
    
    rem Remove the specific text from the file name
    set "new_filename=!filename:%text_to_remove%=!"

    rem Rename the file with the modified name
    ren "%%F" "!new_filename!%%~xF"
)

echo Files with specific_text removed from names.
pause
```